# How can I rewrite my collision logic in my pygame platformer?

Tags: python, pygame

I can't seem to figure out how to write the collision logic for my platformer.

Project File: https://github.com/1NilusNilus/Pygame-Platformer

Player Movement Code:

```
def move(self):
        print(self.POS)

        if self.POS[1] > SCREEN_SIZE[1]:
            self.POS[1] = SCREEN_SIZE[1] - self.SIZE[1]

        self.RECT.x = self.POS[0]
        self.RECT.y = self.POS[1]

        self.VEL[0] = 0
        if self.DIR["left"]:
            self.VEL[0] = -5

        if self.DIR["right"]:
            self.VEL[0] = 5

        self.POS[0] += self.VEL[0]

        

        self.VEL[1] += self.GRAVITY
```

Tile Collision Test Code:

```
def testCollision(self, rect):

        self.RECT.x = self.POS[0]
        self.RECT.y = self.POS[1]

        for tile in self.TILES:
            if rect.colliderect(tile):
                self.hitlist.append(self.RECT)
        return self.hitlist
```

Comment: Collision logic is rough! I've certainly been there before. What problems are you having with this code?

Comment: StackOverflow is generally not the site where people write your code for you. (you'd need to pay somebody if you want that!) We can help point out issues that you might be having and help you on the way, but to get helpful answers, you need to try and meet us halfway. In your case, what are some examples of collisions that don't work? What are self.tiles and self.RECT defined as?

Comment: I'm reposting this question with my collision logic

Comment: Your title says you want to rewrite something, and the question body says you are having trouble writing something (presumably for the first time). Which is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't describe *how* you want the collision to work.  So I will make it up as I go along.

One of the simplest ways to do collision is to test during **attempted** movement.  That is, decide if the proposed move is legal *before* changing the player's co-ordinates.  This works well because the code knows the original player location, and the direction of travel.  So an elegant solution partially moves the player in the desired direction up to the point of collision.

So for starters you seem to be keeping a player `POS` and a player `RECT`.  Why keep two locations? Let's just use the `RECT`.  But keeping Python Style Guide [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) in mind, we'll call it `rect`.

Looking at your existing function, the `move()` moves the player left-right, adds gravity, and handles being on-screen.   IMHO a Player movement function should not be knowing about gravity, so this should be handled somewhere else.  It can simply be passed as part of the y-change.  I'll leave the on-screen test as an exercise for the reader.

So about collisions - I don't know anything about your map, but it's possible that a move could collide with more than 1 object in a single move.  Imagine this single-jump of *dx* pixels, use-case:

[image: movement use-case]

We know this proposed single-jump right collides with 3 objects.  In this implementation of movement, we can only move so-far as to be touching the left-side of left-most terrain element "T2".

Can you see how *knowing* the proposed movement was "right" helps with this?  It allows us to say: "Well moving *dx* pixels right, we would hit 3 things.  So stop at the left-most one".  If your player has *already* moved, and then your collision report says: "Uh-oh, 3 collisions Boss", how can you fix it?  You can't.

So we take the theoretical move, if there's no collisions, well the player can move all of it.  But if there is a collision, we look at the direction of travel, and find the closest thing we hit.  This becomes the limit of movement *for that direction*.  But we can simply handle both *dx* and *dy* in the same manner as independent movements.

[image: move demo]

Reference Code:

```
import pygame
import random

WINDOW_WIDTH  = 500
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500

WHITE = ( 200, 200, 200 )
GREEN = (  30, 240,  80 )
BLUE  = (   3,   5,  54 )

class DummyMap:
    """ A random map of blockable terrain objects.
        Being random, it sometimes unhelpfully puts blocks over the 
        initial player position.  """

    def __init__( self, point_count, x_size=32, y_size=32 ):
        self.blockers = []
        for i in range( point_count ):
            random_x = random.randint( 0, WINDOW_WIDTH )
            random_y = random.randint( 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT )
            self.blockers.append( pygame.Rect( random_x, random_y, x_size, y_size ) )

    def draw( self, surface ):
        for tile in self.blockers:
            pygame.draw.rect( surface, GREEN, tile )
            
    def testCollision( self, rect ):
        """ This function is very much NOT efficeient for large lists.
            Consider using a quad-tree, etc. for faster collisions """
        colliders = []
        for tile in self.blockers:
            if ( tile.colliderect( rect ) ):
                colliders.append( tile )
        return colliders


class Player:
    """ Simple moveable player block, which collides with map elements """

    def __init__( self, x, y ):
        self.image  = pygame.Surface( ( 32, 32 ) )
        self.rect   = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.image.fill( WHITE )

    def draw( self, surface ):
        surface.blit( self.image, self.rect )

    def move( self, dx, dy, game_map ):
        """ Move the player, handling collisions """

        # calculate the target position of any x-move
        if ( dx != 0 ):
            move_rect = player.rect.copy()
            move_rect.move_ip( dx, 0 )

            print( "DEBUG: proposed x-move to (%d, %d)" % ( move_rect.x, move_rect.y ) )

            # Does this new position collide with the map elements?
            collide_rects = game_map.testCollision( move_rect )

            if ( len( collide_rects ) > 0 ):
                # yes collided, determine which object is the nearest
                if ( dx > 0 ):
                    # Going right, get the left-most x out of everything we hit
                    lowest_left_side = min( [ r.left for r in collide_rects ] )
                    # We can only move right as far as this lowest left-side, minus our width
                    final_dx = lowest_left_side - self.rect.right
                else:
                    # Going left, get the right-most x out of everything we hit
                    highest_right_side = max( [ r.right for r in collide_rects ] )
                    # We can only move left as far as the highest right-side
                    final_dx = highest_right_side - self.rect.left # (this is a negative value)
            else:
                final_dx = dx  # no collsiions, no worries

            # Do the x-movement
            self.rect.x += final_dx
            print( "DEBUG: final x-move to (%d, %d)" % ( self.rect.x, self.rect.y ) )

        if ( dy != 0 ):
            move_rect = player.rect.copy()
            move_rect.move_ip( 0, dy )

            print( "DEBUG: proposed y-move to (%d, %d)" % ( move_rect.x, move_rect.y ) )

            # Does this new position collide with the map elements?
            collide_rects = game_map.testCollision( move_rect )

            if ( len( collide_rects ) > 0 ):
                # yes collided, determine which object is the nearest
                if ( dy < 0 ):
                    # Going up, get the bottom-most y out of everything we hit
                    lowest_bottom_side = min( [ r.bottom for r in collide_rects ] )
                    # We can only move up as far as this lowest bottom
                    final_dy = lowest_bottom_side - self.rect.top
                else:
                    # Going down, get the top-most y out of everything we hit
                    highest_top_side = max( [ r.top for r in collide_rects ] )
                    # We can only move down as far as the highest top-side, minus our height
                    final_dy = highest_top_side - self.rect.bottom # (this is a negative value)
            else:
                final_dy = dy  # no collsiions, no worries

            # Do the y-movement
            self.rect.y += final_dy
            print( "DEBUG: final x-move to (%d, %d)" % ( self.rect.x, self.rect.y ) )


                


### initialisation
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )
pygame.display.set_caption("Collision Demo")

# Game elements
player   = Player( WINDOW_WIDTH//2, WINDOW_HEIGHT//2 )
game_map = DummyMap( 37 )

### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

    # Movement keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    dx = 0
    dy = 0 # 2 # gravity sucks
    if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
        dy -= 5
    if ( keys[pygame.K_DOWN] ):
        dy += 5
    if ( keys[pygame.K_LEFT] ):
        dx -= 5
    if ( keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] ):
        dx += 5
    # Try to move the player according to the human's wishes
    player.move( dx, dy, game_map )


    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    window.fill( BLUE )
    game_map.draw( window )
    player.draw( window )
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

pygame.quit()
```